# Set select option 'selected', by value for model pop up

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have an edit button

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-sm btn-primary pull-right edit" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"  data-id="{{$menus->id}}" data-title="{{$menus->title}}"  data-assign="{{$menus->assigned_to}}" onclick="Test({{$key}})">
  <i class="voyager-edit"></i> Edit
</a>
```

The value of `data-assign` is like this:

```
1,2,3
```

I want to split the values and selected dropdown menu. I tried to iterate through the loop using the value in a dynamic selector that utilizes the attribute selector.

```
$('.edit').click(function(e) {  
  var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id'); 
  var assign = $(e.currentTarget).data('assign');

  $.each(assign.split(","), function(i, e) { 
    $("#framework1 option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
  });   
});
```

```html
<select id="framework1" name="Roles[]" multiple class="form-control">
  @foreach($roles as $id=>$name)
    <option value="{{$id}}">{{$name}}</option>
  @endforeach    
</select>
```

I can't set this value to multiple select drop down. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The logic you've shown should work fine. It would be more helpful to see the actual HTML output so that we can verify the values are exactly what you expect them to be. Also, check the console for errors and ensure you're running the jQuery within a document.ready handler

Answer (score 1):

This could be simply achieved using the `this` keyword and `.val()` method.

**NOTE 1:** Make sure the inline-event `onclick` isn't the source of the conflit here.

**NOTE 2:** If the anchor is created dynamically you should use event delegation `on()` like :

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit', (function() {
```

```js
$('.edit').click(function() {
  $("#framework1").val($(this).data('assign').split(","));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-sm btn-primary pull-right edit" data-assign="1,2,3">
  <i class="voyager-edit"></i> Edit
</a>
<br><br>
<select id="framework1" multiple>
  <option value="1">Big Island</option>
  <option value="2">Oahu</option>
  <option value="3">Kauai</option>
  <option value="4">Maui</option>
</select>
```

Comment: -thanks for this reply but got error TypeError: $(...).data(...).split is not a function

Comment: You should make sure that the edit link has `data-assign` attribute.

Comment: have you removed the inline-event `onclick ` ?